# Python Tkinter: set label background (in a canvas) to transparent

Tags: python, tkinter, label, transparency, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a graph using tkinter and I want to have a monthly profit label situated above the point on the graph at which this profit is situated.

The problem I am having is the white background of the label is clipping off the lines in the line graph. Is there any way to set the label background to transparent?

I have tried calling the labels before I make the lines however the label is still on top of the lines when I did that.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Q8Q3XBU.png]

Comment: I think there are no transparencies in tkinter.

Comment: I flagged it wrongly, do not take it into account

Comment: If it's fine to have the label on the graph, just use the `tkinter.Canvas.create_text` function to write the text directly on the graph.